# File found with search function, but not delete function in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a system file in a directory that I can navigate to and actually see, but when I use CMD and call DIR on that directory it doesn't return an entry for the files there. Also if I try to delete one of said files using the DEL command it says 'Could not find (full file path)'. I am trying to figure out why the files are not found/deleted so I can get my batch file to find/delete them. Also, when I run my batch file to scan the directory for files that contain a specific word, it returns results accurately indicating the file's name, which should mean it recognizes that it exists in that search, but then when it follows up with a delete command, it throws that message about not finding the file in question?

Example of my code and the line its return:

```
::hard coded
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"

::hard coded
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys>for /F "eol=: delims=" %F in ('findstr /m example *') do del "%F" 

::result
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys>del "87b9f8355d9ab561e
eb667a5ccb38f87_1fc45d94-7459-4c39-ad73-4958749bb84f" 

::result    
Could Not Find C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\87b9f8355d9ab561e
eb667a5ccb38f87_1fc45d94-7459-4c39-ad73-4958749bb84f
```

Comment: I get "cannot open" messages when trying to run commands on that folder (because even administrators have only access to the folder, but not the files in it). What problem are you trying to solve with this anyway? That folder is one of the physical locations of the certificate store. If you want to remove certificates, you should do it via the `Certificates` MMC snap-in, `certutil` or PowerShell.

Comment: I want to delete files from this directory that contain specific text in them. I can manually open the file in notepad and run a search for the text, then if found, I can close it, and delete it. I'm basically just trying to replicate that action with my batch command.

Comment: I alread understood *what* you want to do. My question was *why* you want to do it, i.e. what you want to achieve by doing it. Also, did you understand my explanation why doing this isn't such a hot idea in the first place?

Comment: Yes I understand that it isn't typically advisable, but I have a program that tends to leave entries here that cause issues when redistributing to the same machine. So I understand entirely it's not typically recommended, but it is what I would like to do.

Comment: Did you try cleaning up these entries using the methods I mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
del /as /q "%F"
```

enter `del /?` for help

Comment: Boom Nailed it! That seems to have done the trick. Thank you kindly sir.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that those files have the `system` attribute set - perhaps you need to clear that attribute first.

```
attrib *
```

will show the attributes (of all files)

```
attrib -s *
```

will clear the "s" attribute (of all files) - at least, for "normal" files. Whether that will work for Microsoft-specials is in the hands of higher powers.

Comment: Sounded like a good idea but unfortunately that call still gets Access Denied. Same result when running the batch file as administrator.